# Calling Jquery Dialog inside Update Panel in master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have to show a dialog popup which is inside an update panel in Master Page. It is called by the tick_event of an ASP_timer which is also in master page. The problem is that the Dialog doesn't get poped up when inside an update panel. If its put outside update panel the whole page gets refreshed and its popups up, but I dont want that.
Any help would be appreciated.
Here's the code for the same:
In Master Page:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenDialog() {
        $("#divEx").dialog();
    }
</script>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="30000" Tick="Timer_Tick"></asp:Timer>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="divEx">"Hello Dialog"</div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In .Cs :

```
protected void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myfunction", "OpenDialog();", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the popup then why you are using timer.

You can create a JavaScript function to show an alert with your message and call it after definite interval by using setTimeout method.

Comment: Here I havnt written any extra code but in Timer_tick, there's some computation also like inserting into DB etc which needs to be done server side only.

Comment: Why server side only?  You can certainly make an AJAX call with JS that will perform any DB operations.

Comment: Ya right @Dean.DePue. you can use the AJAX call or PageMethods to call the server side methods with JS.